# Microphone Device ID

Tags: matlab, usb, audio-recording

I have three USB microphones plugged up to my Macbook Air via a USB hub. In the Audio MIDI I aggregated the devices and selected the aggregate device as the input for the computer. However, 'audiorecorder' is not picking up the device ID.

```
audiodevinfo

ans

{1x1 struct}
{1x1 struct}
```

and it's naming the internal microphone. Is there a way to set a device ID for each individual microphone?

Comment: what information do the input and output structs contain when entering `audiodevinfo`? The ID should simply be 0,1,2,...etc depending on the number of input devices you have.

Comment: yeah yeah, my questions exactly. the (1,0) struct is for the internal microphone, and the (1,1) is null. I don't think Matlab is picking up the availability of the other microphones at all.

Comment: does it pick up the 3 microphones if they are not aggregated. Or are you able to record from these microphones at all in something like [Audacity](http://www.audacity.sourceforge.net) or Garageband?

Comment: From what I've found Audacity can only handle one USB device at a time . Both trial (with an aggregated device and other) and from reading:

http://forum.audacityteam.org/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=5252

Answer (score 0):

You can determine if you have the correct name for a device using

```
mic1 = audiodevinfo(1, 0)
mic2 = audiodevinfo(1, 1)
mic3 = audiodevinfo(1, 2)
```

where the first argument is output/input (0 or 1) and the second argument is the device ID. Then you can address the mics separately, for example by using

```
audiorecorder(Fs, NBITS, NCHANS, ID)
```

and replacing `ID` with `1` for mic2

If you plug any mic in or out of the computer you may need to restart matlab for it to be recognized.

Comment: audiodevinfo(1,0) is picking up the internal microphone, and audiodevinfo(1,1) isn't linking to anything. I attempted to define the microphones using a serial port approach but they weren't showing up.  


http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/serial.html

Comment: Post the full, expanded contents of the audiodevinfo struct in your post to make it easier for us to diagnose.